# Binding to an array or object subscript

Tags: ember.js

I'm wanting to do something that I suspect is quite easy but for some reason can't figure out how to get my head around it:

```
{{#each item in myArray}}
    {{ui-input value=storeMe[@index]}}
{{/each}}
```

In the above case I'd be iterating through a numeric array of things and I want to store values of a UI component using the same numeric index.

Similarly it would be nice to be able to do the following:

```
{{#each item in myArrayOfObjects}}
    {{ui-input value=storeMe[item.id]}}
{{/each}}
```

Where the storage device -- `storeMe` -- is a dictionary whose keys are determined by the `id` property of each item in array of objects.

---

In my particular use-case, I am asking the user to input a strategy for measuring body fat. I use a select box for that:

```
<div class="clearfix downer">
    {{x-selectize 
        options=measurementStrategies 
        labelField="name" 
        placeholder="measurement strategy" 
        valueObject=measurementPoints 
    }}
</div>
```

By binding to the "valueObject" above I get back a simple array of measurement points which are relevant for the user chosen strategy (e.g., chest, thigh, lower back, etc.). I then iterate through these measurement points and want to have a value stored for each one:

```
<div class="downer">
    {{#each point in measurementPoints}}
        <div class="clearfix">
            {{ui-number-input value=model.measurements[point]}}
        </div>
    {{/each}}
```

This doesn't work, of course, because apparently I can't bind to an offset property (aka, `measurements[point]`).

In many cases this type of problem doesn't matter because if I want to manipulate the structure I'm iterating over then the *each* loop provides the indirection. The problem comes when the storage property is hanging off of a different base than that which you are iterating over. So in my case, if I were actually manipulating `point` or a property hanging off of `point` this would be easy because `point` **is** an offset of `measurementPoints` but in my case I'm iterating `measurementPoints` and saving values to `model.measurements`.

Comment: So you want to pair each `point` with a `mean`?

Comment: hmm I guess I’m still not understanding how your specifics connect to what you originally asked. Can you add in the Handlebars code for how you’d *want* to access an object’s properties by key, or an array’s values by index?

Comment: Well I'm able to iterate over the various measurement points with `{{each}}` but each iteration results in the creation of three numeric inputs and one calculated. These values would be associated with the measurement point but stored on the model. So in it's simplest case, if I just wanted to save the calculated average I would want the <input/> component to bind to model.measurements[point]. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don’t see an input element in your more detailed template. If you just write your template like you did in your initial question, using the invalid pseudo-Handlebars, then I’d probably better understand.

Comment: Good point, simplified now.

Comment: Okay, I added an example computed property that’s more applicable to your specifics.

Answer (score 0):

That’s too much logic for Handlebars. You could create a computed property instead that pairs each `item` with each value in `storeMe`, so you can access them as pairs.

You could probably accomplish this with a custom helper, but it seems like a mess to me.

Here’s a rudimentary example, lacking detail on your problem domain:

```
storeMeItemsByIndex: function() {
  var storeMe = this.get('storeMe');
  return this.get('myArray').map(function(item, index) {
    return storeMe[index];
  });
}.property('myArray', 'storeMe'),

storeMeItemsById: function() {
  var storeMe = this.get('storeMe');
  return this.get('myArray').map(function(item) {
    return storeMe[item.id];
  });
}
```

Those would fit your example template code. However, you wouldn’t have access to both the value from `storeMe` and the item at the same time. If you want that, you could just construct object pairs:

```
storeMeItemsByIndex: function() {
  var storeMe = this.get('storeMe');
  return this.get('myArray').map(function(item, index) {
    return {item: item, value: storeMe[index]};
  });
}.property('myArray', 'storeMe'),
```

Or something like that.

With your more specific example, you could do something like this:

```
measurementPointsWithValues: function() {
  var measurements = this.get('model.measurements');
  return this.get('measurementPoints').map(function(point, index) {
    return {point: point, value: measurements.itemAt(index)};
  };
}
```

Then you’d use it in your template like this:

```
{{#each pointAndValue in measurementPointsWithValues}}
  {{! some use of pointAndValue.point, probably}}
  {{ui-number-input value=pointAndValue.value}}
{{/each}}
```

It’s clunky, but it works. I don’t know the details of your object model, but you may benefit from some intermediate objects.

Comment: Really? It must be a pretty common use-case though right? I mean the most basic use-case, no, but a fairly common problem.

Comment: In my current case a user chooses a "strategy" which implies a dynamic set of measurements. Each measurement is then iterated through and the input box is painted on the screen. I just want the storage to adjust to the user-driven event of choosing strategy.

Comment: You can still use a computed property that creates the pairs based on the current strategy. Handlebars doesn’t support accessing arrays except via iteration.

Comment: In my head I was thinking maybe a computed property would be useful but I never got that to a working solution. If its not too much effort could you share your idea in code shorthand?

Comment: Sure, can you just specify how `storeMe` works? Like, you say that a strategy is somehow involved, but how?

Comment: Thanks Buck. Let me digest this and see how I can adapt it.